# How to link a subfolder from one git repository into another?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

I have 2 git repositories in following structure.

```
Repository1 -> src
            |
            -> res


 Repository2 -> src
             |
             -> res
```

I want to link subfolders in Repository2 to Repository1, so that final folder structure would look something like :

```
Repository1 -> src -> Repository2src
            |
            -> res -> Repository2res
```

Is there any way I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly with Git, considering even a shallow clone would still involve the Repository2 parent folder (instead of directly its src or res folder).

I would recommend:

- Repo1 parent repo with Repo2 declared as [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)
- Two symlinks:

  - Repo1/src/Repository2src pointing to ../Repo2/src
  - Repo2/res/Repository2res pointing to ../Repo2/res